# Remove the repeating code by passing the instance dynamically

Tags: c#, reflection

In my project, I am using fluent API to configure the entities and I need to add it to `AplicationDbContext's OnModelCreating` method like below.

```
builder.AddConfiguration(new HolidayConfig());
builder.AddConfiguration(new HomeworkConfig());
builder.AddConfiguration(new HouseConfig());
builder.AddConfiguration(new HouseStudentConfig());
builder.AddConfiguration(new ParentConfig());
builder.AddConfiguration(new SchoolAddressConfig());
builder.AddConfiguration(new SchoolClassConfig());
```

This list of classes is growing daily and I need to add newly created configuration each time.

I tried to do this using `Reflection` but got no success. I got all the classes (that I need to add) using the code below, but unable to create the instance of that class. Using `Activator.CreateInstance` returns `Object` that I am unable to pass on it.

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(BlockConfig));
var types = assembly.GetTypes();
List<Type> classes = new List<Type>();
foreach (var item in types)
{
    if(item.Name.EndsWith("Config"))
    {
        classes.Add(item);
        //Got the class list, now I need to create instance of each class in the list.
        //How to achieve that.
    }
}
```

Is there any way to add it using some code in which we create objects of the classes and pass it to the given method. Thanks

*Edit:*

```
public static void AddConfiguration<T>(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder,
 EntityTypeConfiguration<T> configuration) where T : class
{
    configuration.Map(modelBuilder.Entity<T>());
}

public abstract class EntityTypeConfiguration<T>
    where T : class
{
    public abstract void Map(EntityTypeBuilder<T> builder);
}

public class BlockConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Block>
{
    public override void Map(EntityTypeBuilder<Block> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(b => b.Name)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(32);

        builder.Property(b => b.Code)
            .HasMaxLength(3);
    }
}
```

There are many classes similiar to the `BlockConfig`.

Comment: What type does `AddConfiguration` expect?

Comment: objects of `config` classes as shown in the above code.

Comment: Please clarify, show the signature of `builder.AddConfiguration`. I asked which type it expected, meaning what does it say in the method signature.

Comment: Please check the edit.

Comment: To create an instance use Activator, that's not the problem here, the problem is satisfying the `<T>` of `AddConfiguration`, you'll need to use reflection, get the methodinfo object for that method and use `MakeGenericMethod` in each iteration of your loop to create a generic version of the method with the right `<T>`. Unless you can cast each instance to `BlockConfig` and that would be enough, then do that.

Comment: As a control question, will this do the right thing? `builder.AddConfiguration((BlockConfig)new HolidayConfig());` ?

Comment: No, It will not work as every Config class has configurations related to that entity. For example, `BlockConfig` has configurations for `Block` entity, `HolidayConfig` has configurations for 'Holiday' entity and so on.

Comment: You will still have an **instance** of the appropriate type, it's just that you've cast it to the base class. Did you verify that it won't work or do you **think** it won't work? Do you understand why we're harping on about casting and what that does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I gather from your question and comments, is that you want to get all types that end with `Config`, and call the `Map` function on this object with the correct `EntityTypeBuilder<T>` value.

You can do this by using reflection to call the generic method on the ModelBuilder class.

So, given that you have `types` as an array of your configuration types you can do:

```
var builder = new ModelBuilder();

// Get method
MethodInfo entityMethodModelBuilder = typeof(ModelBuilder)
                                               .GetMethod(nameof(ModelBuilder.Entity));

foreach (var type in types) {
    // Get the Generic Type of the EntityTypeConfiguration
    var entType = type.BaseType.GetGenericArguments().First();

    // Ensure the Entity method is Generic.
    MethodInfo genericEmmb = entityMethodModelBuilder.MakeGenericMethod(entType);

    // Get EntityTypeBuilder<entType>
    var value = genericEmmb.Invoke(builder, null);

    // Get new type
    var config = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    // Get method
    MethodInfo mapMethod = type.GetMethod("Map");
    // Call :Map() on the config object
    mapMethod.Invoke(config, new object[] { value });
}
```

However, the above code you'll need to add some checks to ensure the type you are trying to parse is actually an configuration type and not some object that just happens to have 'Config' in its name. Otherwise be prepared to vague errors in the future if someone forgets how it works.

---

As an alternative you could use an *non generic* interface and pass the ModelBuilder object to it. Something like the following:

```
public interface IEntConfig {
    void MapEntity(ModelBuilder builder);
}
```

and add to your BlockConfig class (and others):

```
public void MapEntity(ModelBuilder builder) => Map(builder.Entity<Block>());
```

That will make it a bit safer as you can do:

```
var entConfigType = typeof(IEntConfig);

// Init types
Assembly.GetAssembly(entConfigType)
        .GetTypes()
        .Where(type => entConfigType.IsAssignableFrom(type) && type != entConfigType)
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(type => ((IEntConfig) Activator.CreateInstance(type)).MapEntity(builder));
```

This keeps the reflection part to a minimum and ensures that you only get the exact types you want configured. However, will require some extra code in your config classes.

If you have access over the abstract base class (or are willing to create  one that inherits the current `EntityTypeConfiguration`) you can also implement the interface there. Requiring you to only change the abstract base class in your Config classes. Such as:

```
public abstract class MyEntityTypeConfiguration<T> : EntityTypeConfiguration<T>, IEntConfig
         where T : class {
    public void MapEntity(ModelBuilder builder) => Map(builder.Entity<T>());
}

public class BlockConfig : MyEntityTypeConfiguration<Block> {
    public override void Map(EntityTypeBuilder<Block> builder) {
        // Do stuff
    } 
}
```

*Note: if you use the abstract class approach, you'll need add the check `!type.IsAbstract` to ensure you don't try to initialize the abstract class.*

Comment: I am trying with your given solution and seems to me that I am going in right direction. Currently, there are some exceptions arriving while implementing it. I will try and tell you soon. Thank!

Comment: Finally, it worked with your code. I just changed `var entityMethodModelBuilder = typeof(ModelBuilder).GetMethods()
                  .Where(m => m.Name == nameof(ModelBuilder.Entity)
                                                           && (m.IsGenericMethod == true)
                                                           && m.GetParameters().Count() == 0)
                                                           .First();` to select the generic mathod with no parameters, as there were two generic methods named `Entity`.

Comment: I feel that now I have no need of Extension method named `AddConfiguration`. Am I correct?

Comment: @vivek if you were just using it for loading these classes, it can indeed be  removed.

Comment: @vivek as a note, if there is only a single method without parameters named 'Entity' you can use `GetMethod(nameof(ModelBuilder.Entity), new Type[0])` to specify you want the method without any parameter values.

Answer (score 0):

In your classes you can implement an intervace like **IConfigInterface** and use reflection in this way with [Activator.CreateInstance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var type = typeof(IConfigInterface);
var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
    .Where(p => type.IsAssignableFrom(p));
foreach (var item in types)
{
    classes.Add(Activator.CreateInstance(item));    
}
```

Another way is:

```
foreach (Type item in System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                 .Where(mytype => mytype.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IConfigInterface)))) 
{
    classes.Add(Activator.CreateInstance(item));
}
```

Comment: Plese read the question and understand it well. As shown in the first code, I need to pass an object. I am also getting the list of all classes but unable to create an instance of that type. That is the actual problem.

Comment: I think that Activator.CreateInstance can help you. I have changed the code. Let me know.

Comment: `Activator.CreateInstance` is giving me an `Object` type, but need a specific on like `BlockConfig` if the item type is `BlockConfig`. How to cast it.

Comment: cast it, @vivek! `(BlockConfig)Activator.CreateInstance(item)`

Comment: @Rubens, you are not getting my point. `BlockConfig` is just an example of such class. I have a lot of such classes. It has to be cast back to item's type that I do not know exactly.

Comment: all those classes (probably) inherit the same base class; use the most common class to cast them all

Comment: I agree with the solution proposed by @Rubens.

Comment: I asked what  type the method expected, you said the config type in the question, which is BlockConfig. If that is true (and it isn't generic and expecting T) then you **absolutely and definitely can** cast to BlockConfig and pass the resulting reference.